# Customize List of Symbols

Tags: symbols, glossaries, nomenclature

I would like to create such a list of symbols:
[image]

So I have to have **three columns and on top two sections for greek and for latin symbols**... Is `\listofsymbols` even a good choice? Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish it?

This is my code so far:

```
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Preamble
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

%Seitenlayout
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}

%Deutsche Umlaute
\usepackage{ngerman}

%Mathematische Symbole und Zeichen
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

%Symbolverzeichnis
\usepackage[final]{listofsymbols} 
%draft = Entwurfsmodus, no = Symbol wurde nicht verwendet
%final = nur die verwendeten Symbole werden angezeigt


% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Anfang von Dokumententext
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Verzeichnisse
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\tableofcontents


\newpage
\opensymdef
\newsym[Dichte der Luft]{rhoL}{\mathbb{\rho}_{L}}
\newsym[Globalstrahlung]{G}{\text{G}}
\closesymdef

\renewcommand{\symheadingname}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\listofsymbols

\newpage

% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Beginn des Inhalts
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Einleitung}
\rhoL
\G

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with this, which was fine for me, but doesn't have a sort function:

```
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Preamble
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

%Seitenlayout
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}

%Deutsche Umlaute
\usepackage{ngerman}

%Mathematische Symbole und Zeichen
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Symbolverzeichnis
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\nomenclature[3]{#1 & #2 & #3\\}
\usepackage{array}

% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Anfang von Dokumententext
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Verzeichnisse
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\tableofcontents

% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Einbettung des Symbolverzeichnisses
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\newpage
\chapter*{Symbolverzeichnis}
\chaptermark{Symbolverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Symbolverzeichnis}

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.275}
\textbf{Griechische Symbole}
\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{114pt}@{}p{114pt}@{}p{225pt}@{}}
\nomenclature{\textbf{Symbol}}{\textbf{Einheit}}{\textbf{Bezeichnung}}
\endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page

\nomenclature{ρ\textsubscript{L}}{[kg/m\textsuperscript{3}]}{Dichte der Luft}
\nomenclature{N}{kg}{DThe number of angels per needle point . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .}
\nomenclature{A}{kg}{The area of the needle point}
\nomenclature{sigma}{kg}{The total mass of angels per unit area}
\nomenclature{m}{kg}{The mass of one angel}

\end{longtable}


\textbf{Lateinische Symbole}
\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{114pt}@{}p{114pt}@{}p{225pt}@{}}
\nomenclature{\textbf{Symbol}}{\textbf{Einheit}}{\textbf{Bezeichnung}}
\endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page

\nomenclature{G}{[W/m\textsuperscript{2}]}{Globalstrahlung}
\nomenclature{N}{kg}{The number of angels per needle point . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .}
\nomenclature{A}{kg}{The area of the needle point}
\nomenclature{sigma}{kg}{The total mass of angels per unit area}
\nomenclature{m}{kg}{The mass of one angel}

\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\newpage

% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Beginn des Inhalts
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Einleitung}

\end{document}
```